# How to avoid JavaFX drop shadow effect from overlaying a button next to it and being unable to press the button?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am using JavaFX to style a GridPane with a drop shadow.  The drop shadow has a shadow blur kernel of 10 pixels ([JavaFX CSS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect)).  A button is located above the GridPane and because the shadow blur kernel is spreading ten pixels out from the GridPane, I cannot click the lower half of the button.  Evidently because the shadow blur kernel is overlaying the lower half of the button, I cannot click it.  A few possible solutions are to move the button further away from the GridPane or to decrease the reach of the shadow blur kernel, but is there another solution to this issue without doing either of those things?  Thank you to everyone in advance!

Comment: Use layers, to move to button being occluded so it ends up above the one doing the occluding?

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#viewOrderProperty

Answer (score 0):

By calling the toFront() method on the buttons after the style was added to the GridPane, the buttons rose to the top and were fully clickable again.